# How to parse subprocess output via regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, subprocess, python-re

I want to search in `ipconfig` command output in Windows using python and subprocess and display the interface and IP only, I tried using `re` module, but I'm new to this and don't have much experience.

This is the output of `ipconfig`

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

How can I show only the Adapter name, and IPv4 Address?

Full python code:

```
import re, subprocess

command = subprocess.run(['ipconfig'], shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(F'>> command')
```

Comment: It seems like you can just look for lines that dont have white space in the beginning and end with a `:`

Comment: Could you please write the proper code for the task?

Comment: You should try writing the code yourself first, following the documentation for the `re` module and the many examples you can find here on StackOverflow and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively simple task to do without regex using Python string methods. Please see the comments for an explanation.

```
output = """Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :"""

# Get the text as individual lines by splitting on new line char
lines: list = output.split("\n")

# Get name as first line, removing trailing :
name: str = lines[0][:-1]

# Loop through each line, looking for IPv4 Address
for line in lines:
    if "IPv4 Address" in line:
        # Get IPv4 address by splitting on :, taking final element and then stripping whitespace
        address: str = line.split(":")[-1].strip()

# Print results
print(f"Name: {name}")
print(f"IPv4 Address: {address}")
```

PS. you should attempt to write the code yourself first as you will get much faster responses, as we like to see that you have at least tried to solve the problem yourself.